# Navigating with the Backbone router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone.Router class setup and everything is working perfectly. However, there is a little (maybe a bit blocking) inconvenience.

In order to navigate using the Backbone Router, I use the following code

```
myrouter.navigate('/search_term/2/filter1+filter2/');
```

This works as it should. However, the different parameters of the URL are not updated in the same place. For example, the user might move to the next page (3) and the search term and filters shouldn't be updated.

What I want to be able to do is something like this

```
myrouter.navigate(':route_id', ':route_value');
```

For example, I can do

```
myrouter.navigate(':query', 'search_term');
myrouter.navigate(':pagination', '5');
```

Can Backbone do this? If not, any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this myself.

The solution was to listen to the change of the models by binding to the change event in a similar fashion to what I do when submitting a request.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a function your self that extends the backbone routes to work with the way you want.

If you read routes source code, you will see that they only convert you pattern for a regexp pattern, is very simple, then apply the method target with the arguments matched by the regexp.

So if you want a reverse route to navigate or something like that you can apply your self extending Backbone.Route

Something like this:

```
myrouter = Backbone.Router.extends({
    navigate: function(a, b) {
        // Do something with my args here
        var result = doSomething(a, b);

        // Then execute backbone's official navigate with the results
        Backbone.Router.navigate.apply(this, result);
    }
});
```

Create your function to `doSomething` to work's how you need to reverse create your route.

But there isn't a Backbone native way to do this, the router ins't mutch advanced feature.

Comment: Not sure I did understand you correctly. If the user navigated to "/search_term/pagination/". Why do I need to navigate again to this page and how does that help?